# How to get the output for the following code?

Tags: perl

I have a file output1.txt which has one string per line. I want to extract the strings which contain either of the substrings 'rxd' or 'txd' or 'cts' or 'rts' along with '*UART*' which should be there in the string with any four of these and then write it back in output1.txt but I am getting a blank file after running this code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @array1;

open my $abc , '<', 'output1.txt' or die $!;
my @array = <$abc>;
foreach $_ (@array) {
    my @array1 = grep {
        ( /txd/ || /rxd/ || /cts/ || /rts/ ) && ( /_UART_/ )
    } (@array);
}
close $abc;

open my $f1 , '>', 'output1.txt' or die $!;
foreach (@array1) {
    print $f1 "$_\n";
}
close $f1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `my @array1 = grep ...`, remove the `my`. You're declaring a *new* `@array1` inside the foreach loop that doesn't exist outside of the loop, while the original `@array1` stays empty.

Comment: Thanks its working now :) ...One more thing  when we grep from array and put in array1 then a new line charater is added at the end of each element on its own?

Comment: @Grace90 no, it was already there when you read it from the file. Use `chomp` to remove it.